# Environment variables non accessible in CloudControl deploy script

Tags: yii, composer-php, cloudcontrol

I have a script being called by Composer that should run some database procedures. However, that script have no environment variables and thus is not connecting to the database as expected.

I tried to access the application using SSH and all the environment variables are there, accessible by the PHP command-line client.

Excerpt from the deploy output:

```
-----> Receiving push
#!/usr/bin/env php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer successfully installed to: /srv/tmp/builddir/code/composer.phar
Use it: php /srv/tmp/builddir/code/composer.phar
       Welcome to Phundament

       Installing application...

       Array
       (
       )
       bool(false)
       bool(false)
```

Those three debug outputs were generated by (yes, I've created the APPLICATION_ENV var as described in the guides):

```
print_r($_ENV);
var_dump(getenv('CRED_FILE'));
var_dump(getenv('APPLICATION_ENV'));
```

Comment: I also noticed that, seeing those commands' output in my live application, while CRED_FILE exists, the custom APPLICATION_ENV does not.

Comment: For PHP we do not write credentials from general add-ons or the custom config add-on into environment variables but instead only make them available via the creds.json file. This is to protect people from exposing their database and other sensitive credentials via a public phpinfo page.

Comment: Hmmm so in this case I should access the application environment through the credentials file too? I would never figure that out. I noticed the yii guide cites getenv() to be working, although the code uses the credentials file correctly. This should be clear in your documentation.

Comment: I would add here that using custom config vars through that cumbersome credentials file is totally AWFUL. While I do understand to have the addons credentials there, for security, it's just horrible to discover my application environment using `$credentials['CONFIG']['CONFIG_VARS']['APPLICATION_ENV']`. This is very deep and totally uneeded. I should also add that some addons have repeated strings in their keys, such as `$credentials['MONGOLAB']['MONGOLAB_URI']`. There's no need to make sure that the URI inside MONGOLAB key is from MONGOLAB lol...

Comment: Since for e.g. Java and Ruby the credentials are exported as environment variables per default and environment variables are a flat namespace, the prefix is actually required. In the creds.json file the nesting was added primarily for readability purposes. But this discussion is getting way off topic.

Comment: I agree it's getting out of topic, and that's why I usually find weird when companies try to use community forums for user support (:

Comment: Although, I still must add that I see little reason for the prefix appear in the creds.json file. After all, it's a different way of accessing the information, right? So it would make sense to see env vars namespaced and the json object with an hierarchical organization only, without that cluttering prefixes.

Comment: Oh. And yet I see no reason for being unable to access the variables configured on config.free add on in the environment. I can understand protecting the addons credentials, but as those variables are mine, I should know what to do with them, right? I say that because all the other PaaS that I have already used give us a much cleaner way to set env vars - a quite common task on app development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct. During the push and building of the image, no Add-on credentials are available. To run database migrations or similar scripts I suggest you use the cctrlapp [run command](https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/Platform%20Documentation#secure-shell-ssh). You can easily script this together with a push and deploy command.

Comment: Thanks! Any special tip about env vars on normal application run, as mentioned in my comment?

Comment: It depends on the language if env vars are enabled or disabled by default. You can always overwrite the default behaviour. https://www.cloudcontrol.com/dev-center/platform-documentation#enabling/disabling-credentials-environment-variables